# Ошибка NotSerializableException

Tags: java

```
    package com.company;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private String filename = "users.txt";
    private ArrayList people = new ArrayList();

    private void run() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1: Добавить ");
        System.out.println("2: Посмотреть ");
        System.out.println("0: Выход ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int c;
        do {
            c = sc.nextInt();

            switch (c) {
                case 1:
                    PersoneAdd();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    PersoneView();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Выход");
                    break;
            }
        } while (c > 0);
    }
    void PersoneView() {
        ArrayList<Person> newPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {
            newPeople = (ArrayList<Person>) ois.readObject();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        for (Person p : newPeople)
            System.out.printf("Имя:%s \r  Регион: %s \n ", p.name, p.address);
    }
    private void PersoneAdd() {
        String namee, adress;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" имя : ");
        namee = sc.next();

        System.out.print(" Регион: ");
        adress = sc.next();

        people.add(new Person(namee,adress));

        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))) {
            oos.writeObject(people);
            System.out.println("Запись произведена");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    class Person implements Serializable {
        String name;
        String address;
        Person(String n, String aa) {
            name = n;
            address = aa;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Main menu = new Main();
        menu.run();
    }

}
```

> writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.company.Main

Как исправить ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы исправить , нужно имплементировать игтерфейс Serializable

```
public class Main implements Serializable
```

А во избежании проблем с сериализацией добавьте такое поле

```
private transient static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Цифру можно написать любую, но менять ее нельзя, иначе опять получите исключение

Comment: Спасибо , работает .